# Could not install R package source in R-studio

Tags: r

I have a source of one R package (http://stat.snu.ac.kr/heeseok/autots). I would like to install it in R-studio, however, I got an error.

Here is my try:

```
install.packages("/Users/Mary/Downloads/autots_2.3.3.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")
```

Here is the error:

```
ERROR: dependencies ‘fBasics’, ‘fNonlinear’, ‘fGarch’, ‘fUtilities’, ‘tsDyn’, ‘tseriesChaos’ are not available for package ‘autots’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/autots’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘/Users/Mary/Downloads/autots_2.3.3.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: have you tried to install these packages first? `fBasics`, `fNonlinear`, `fGarch`, `fUtilities`, `tsDyn`, `tseriesChaos`?

Comment: @Edo, yes  I did and that was fine